# React Native Allow only lowercase input for TextInput

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to have a TextInput for react native that allows only lowercase input?

As of now, tried this code:

```
state = { login: '' }

changeUsernameToLowercase = (input) => {
  var temp = input.toLowerCase()
  this.setState({login: temp})
}

<TextInput
  onChangeText={(login) => this.changeUsernameToLowercase(login)}
  value={this.state.login}
  autoCapitalize='none' />
```

But it seems to not work on some android devices.

Maybe there is a more efficient way on doing this?

Comment: What happens if you replace `input.toLowerCase()` with say `input.toLocaleLowerCase('en-US')`

Comment: @DacreDenny the outcome is the same

Comment: Have you tried `value={this.state.login.toLowerCase()}` ?

Comment: On my Android device `value={username.toLowerCase()}` has a strange behaviour. If I type an uppercase char, it is correctly shown as lowercase, but on the next type, instead of appending just the new char, it appends the old and the new one.

Comment: @iconso it's a bug that still exists. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11068

Comment: I just tried on an android emulator and it seems it has been fixed up!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might solve your problem, it works for me.
Add these three lines inside `TextInput`, original [answer source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11068#issuecomment-586346549)

```
 autoCapitalize="none"
 secureTextEntry={true}
 keyboardType={"visible-password"}
```

example

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, TextInput } from "react-native";


export default function App () {
    const [text,setText] = useState('');
    
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
           autoCapitalize="none"
           secureTextEntry={true}
           keyboardType={"visible-password"}
          style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1,width:"100%"}}
          value={text}
          onChangeText={ text => setText(text.toLowerCase()) }
        />
      </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you keep struggling with this and the `autoCapitalize="none"` is not working, try this:

First, your TexInput:

```
<TextInput
   placeholder="Nombre completo"
   placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.4)"
   style={styles.inputField}
   selectionColor={'white'}
   onChangeText={value => onChange(value, 'name')}
   value={name}
   autoCorrect={false}
 />
```

**Notice that I'm not using autoCapitalize but I'm adding a style prop**

Finally, I'm going to capitalize or lowercase using CSS with the `textTransform` property:

```
inputField: {
    marginTop: 10,
    width: '90%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: colors.primary,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: colors.primary,
    fontSize: 18,
    backgroundColor: colors.background,
    textTransform: 'lowercase',
  }
```

Hope this helps!