# toLowerCase on TextInput value is creating duplicate text if capital letter created

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

This one's an interesting one.

I created a TextInput that takes a value, then lower cases it, adds it to state, and sets it as the default value. On my android physical device, if you force a capital letter ( autocapitalize is set to none), and then quickly tap other letters, it will duplicate and add extra text.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Here's a snack https://snack.expo.io/Hk1reKHJ4

Run it on your android or on the simulator, tap the upper case button on the keyboard, tap a few other letters, tap the upper case again, tap a few other letters, and you should set this error.

Thanks!

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      text: ''
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={ styles.inputContainer }
          defaultValue={ this.state.text }
          autoCapitalize="none"
          onChangeText={ value => this.setState({ 
            text: value.trim().toLowerCase()
            })}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately this is an issue that has been open for a couple of years with no solution, you can check [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11068), no one found a solution. There is a temporary workaround until the React Native team fixes this bug as it seems to be taking too long, check it out [here](https://github.com/nikolaiwarner/react-native-text-input-reset).

Answer (score 10):

add these three lines inside `TextInput`, it should fix the problem, original [answer source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64057635/7784354)

```
 autoCapitalize="none"
 secureTextEntry={true}
 keyboardType={"visible-password"}
```

see my this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64057635/7784354) for example

Comment: keyboardType={"visible-password"} throws an error in ios simulator

Answer (score 2):

The autoCapitalize prop worked for me.

```
autoCapitalize="none"
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not agree with the selected answer. The link provided in it worked for me.

```
secureTextEntry={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? false : true}
keyboardType={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? null : 'visible-password'}
autoCapitalize="characters"
```

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11068#issuecomment-586346549

Comment: Use `default` for ios, because `null` throws a a type mismatch in Typescript `keyboardType={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'default' : 'visible-password'}`

Answer (score 0):

I made this hack:
https://snack.expo.dev/@bzozoo/duplications-at-upper-or-lowercase-async-problem-solution
Unfortunately, it is quite a compromise solution.
Input is apparently slower due to the asynchronous function

Comment: Do not leave embedded links in a question, links break, either copy the code or use a screenshot.

Answer (score -3):

I found a solution for this issue
add `toLowercase()` when you posting data

```
 axios.post("api/login", { emailid: emailid.trim().toLowerCase()})
```